# Intersystems IRIS Data Platform cant change default password

Tags: docker, intersystems, intersystems-iris

I am currently testing the docker container for the InterSystems IRIS Data Platform. I want to change the default password with this line (from dockerhub instruction: https://hub.docker.com/_/intersystems-iris-data-platform/plans/222f869e-567c-4928-b572-eb6a29706fbd?tab=instructions):

```
 docker run --name my-iris -d --publish 9091:51773 --publish 9092:52773 --volume /home/user1/:/durable store/intersystems/iris-community:2020.2.0.204.0 --password-file /durable/password/password.txt
```

My path to password is: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test\DockerProjekt\warenverwaltung\container\IRISDataPlatform\password\password.txt

It says that I must use the absolute path, but i am not that comfortable what exactly is the absolute path. I tried:

```
docker run --name my-iris -d --publish 9091:51773 --publish 9092:52773 --volume /container/IRISDataPlatform/password/:/durable 92ecaf86671c --password-file /durable/password.txt
```

But in Docker Desktop I see that the container was exited with the error:

> [INFO] Changing InterSystems IRIS password...
>
> [ERROR] 20200630-10:05:56:906696500 Error: Password file
> '/durable/password.txt' not found
>
> [ERROR] Command "changePassword.sh /durable/password.txt" exited with
> status 256
>
> [FATAL] Error changing InterSystems IRIS password

Info: I created an image via Dockerfile, so 92ecaf is my Image ID. It is exactly the same like store/intersystems/iris-community:2020.2.0.204.0. The image was build in the directory:
"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test\DockerProjekt\warenverwaltung"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Docker on Windows, quite tricky. First of all what I can see, that you use the wrong path on your local Windows machine, Linux-way instead of Windows-way.
You may find some more info, how it can be configured on windows [in this article](https://community.intersystems.com/post/using-intersystems-iris-containers-docker-windows). If you will have more questions, better to ask it there, as there are many more people who can help you with it.